# Tomcat: correct way to find a resource?

Tags: java, tomcat, resources, path

I've working on a big application deployed on a Tomcat server.  There's only one .jsp page and all the UI is done using ext-js.

There are a lot of .java classes.  In one of these class (which is performing validation), I'd like to add XML validation and to do this I need to access the *.xsd* file.

My problem is that I don't know how to cleanly find the path to my .xsd file.

I'll put the .xsd files in a repertory next to css/, images/, etc.

I know how to this in a crappy way: I call *System.getProperty("user.home")* and from there I find my webapp, the *xsd/* folder, and the *.xsd* files.

But what is a "clean" way to do this?

Where am I supposed to find the path to my webapp (or to my webapp resources) and how am I supposed to pass this information down to the *.java* class that performs the validation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For files in public web content the [`ServletContext#getRealPath()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) is indeed the way to go.

```
String relativeWebPath = "/path/to/file.xsd";
String absoluteDiskPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(relativeWebPath);
File file = new File(absoluteDiskPath);
// ...
```

However, I can't imagine that there is ever intent to serve the XSD file into the public and also the Java class which needs the XSD doesn't seem to be a servlet. So, I'd suggest to just put XSD file in the classpath and grab from there instead. Assuming that it's been placed in the package `com.example.resources`, you can load it from the classpath as follows:

```
String classpathLocation = "com/example/resources/file.xsd";
URL classpathResource = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(classpathLocation);
// Or:
InputStream input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(classpathLocation);
```

Comment: thanks a lot.  In the second case, is it good practice to just drop the file on the classpath?  (I'll probably have a new question regarding how to do this)

Comment: It's certainly a normal practice for resources of Java classes. The classpath is there where your Java classes also are :) Create a package or reuse an existing package and put the XSD file there. That's it.

Answer (score 2):

`getServletContext().getRealPath("/")` is what you need.

See [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Doesnt work in tomcat